# Word for A Posteriori Argument?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was on the fence on my position on a highly controversial national discussion, and I finally I was able to take a side on it.

I noticed I had a arguments that helped me to decide my position on it that were conceived by me before taking a side.

Then, I noticed that I soon as I took the side, more arguments came flooding in (maybe from the news?). Those helped me to justify my new position and to make it stronger. However, I feel like I'm cheating with those. They didn't help me to make the decision, and they are somehow "convenient" now, so I can sleep better at night.

Is there a word or concept to distinguish between those two types of arguments? I was thinking of calling them "a posteriori arguments", but it doesn't really convey the idea well.

Comment: look up "confirmation bias"

Comment: @Esther Thank you so much! That's what I wanted to find (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias). It seems the antidote is critical thinking.

Comment: If you want to ask questions about the arguments, [philosophy.se] is the place.

Comment: It is not clear why you feel that using these arguments is cheating. If they really do support the position, there is nothing wrong with using them to justify it, even though they did not initially lead you to adopt it. *A posteriori* would definitely be the wrong word to use for the purpose, though (notwithstanding its literal meaning), as it is well established as a technical term for something else.